# Generating and centering form with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to generate and centering form. I'm write the following code:

```
        var frm = document.createElement("form");
        var overlay = document.createElement("div");
        var helper= document.createElement("div");
        helper.setAttribute("style", "display:inline-block; width:0; heigth:100%; vertical-align: middle; background-color: green;");
        overlay.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; \n\
                            opacity: 0.8; background-color: black;");
        frm.setAttribute("method", "get");
        frm.setAttribute("style", "display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; width:20%; border:2px solid white; padding: 30px; \n\
                        background-color:#F7F7F7; font-family: \"Arial\", \"sans-serif\"; font-weight: 100;\n\
                        font-size:12px; opacity: 1;");
        document.body.appendChild(overlay);
        overlay.appendChild(frm);
        overlay.appendChild(helper);
```

I'm expected that form `frm` will be located at hte center of the div `overlay`. But I've only a horizontal centering, not vertical. How to fix this?

Comment: you made small typo> heigth:100%, should be height:100%

Answer (score 0):

Centering:

http://jsfiddle.net/XHFKL/1/

```
var frm = document.createElement("form");
        var overlay = document.createElement("div");
        var helper= document.createElement("div");
        helper.setAttribute("style", "display:inline-block; width:0; height:100%; vertical-align: middle; background-color: green;");
        overlay.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; \n\
opacity: 0.8; background-color: black; text-align:center;");
        frm.setAttribute("method", "get");
frm.setAttribute("style", "display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center; width:20%; border:2px solid white; padding: 30px; \n\
background-color:#F7F7F7; font-family: \"Arial\", \"sans-serif\"; font-weight: 100; margin:0 auto;\n\
                        font-size:12px; opacity: 1;");
        document.body.appendChild(overlay);
        overlay.appendChild(frm);
        overlay.appendChild(helper);
```